# VPATH target failure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have no idea how to express this little problem other than by "VPATH Failure", and searching for that brought me nowhere, so now I'm giving it a go, throwing my issue into the pool.

I'm working on a simple makefile here and I ran into a problem, that I am completely stumped by.
I made a first original version, that I got working all fine and dandy:

```
// Variable pre-processing stuff up here
VPATH =  ./src/ ./include/ 

// Usual phony targets in here

$(OBJF)Utilities$(R).o: Utilities.cpp Utilities.hpp
    @echo Building $@
    @echo $<
    @$(CXX) $(FLAGS) -Iinclude -c $< -o $@

$(OBJF)Settings$(R).o: Settings.cpp Settings.hpp
    @echo Building $@
    @echo $<
    @$(CXX) $(FLAGS) -Iinclude -c $< -o $@

// More file targets down here
```

As proven by the make output

```
lex@Lex-Laptop:~/Dev/LHArch$ make RELEASE=STATIC rebuild
Removing object files and outputs...
Cleaning done.
Building objs/Release/Static/Utilities.o
./src/Utilities.cpp
Building objs/Release/Static/Settings.o
./src/Settings.cpp
```

That's nice.
For the sake of removing some redundancy with the dependencies, I thought it to be a good idea to put the code into their own targets, in this manner:

```
$(OBJF)Utilities$(R).o: Utilities.cpp
    @echo Building $@
    @echo $<
    @$(CXX) $(FLAGS) -Iinclude -c $< -o $@

Utilities.cpp: Utilities.hpp

$(OBJF)Settings$(R).o: Settings.cpp
    @echo Building $@
    @echo $<
    @$(CXX) $(FLAGS) -Iinclude -c $< -o $@

Settings.cpp: Settings.hpp
```

That is all I changed. I expected it to work as perfectly as it did before, but it only partially did:

```
lex@Lex-Laptop:~/Dev/LHArch$ make RELEASE=STATIC rebuild
Removing object files and outputs...
Cleaning done.
Building objs/Release/Static/Utilities.o
./src/Utilities.cpp
Building objs/Release/Static/Settings.o
Settings.cpp
g++: error: Settings.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:101: recipe for target 'objs/Release/Static/Settings.o' failed
make: *** [objs/Release/Static/Settings.o] Error 1
```

It found and replaced the path of Utilities, but not for Settings apparently. They are in the same folder, the commands are the same for the both of them. I honestly have no clue what is wrong and it sort of ruins my plan.

Have you guys for any wise words on this?
Did I stumble upon something genuine here, or am I just a dumbbutt who hasn't read up on his homework?

Comment: @downhillFromHere Twisting and turning it in my head, I do see now that my logic may have failed me, when I thought up this idea. After all, it runs the target when the dependency is younger than the target itself, and in making a code file a target with another code file as a dependency, it would try to run the target, although without achieving anything. The code file doesn't really get updated in anyway by that, it doesn't really work. It only works when the target is actually updated in the process.
I'm going back to the drawing board then! Cheers for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this [rule](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) (link provided by [Etan Reisner)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner)  that `VPATH` and `vpath` should only be used for prerequisites, not for targets.

In your case, `VPATH` behaves "unpredictably" as soon as you put your `.cpp` files both as targets and prerequisites. The good news is that there's no redundancy in your first version. You do want the `.o` to be rebuilt if either of the `.cpp` and `.hpp` is updated. In fact, you **don't** want

```
Utilities.cpp: Utilities.hpp
```

since this will try to rebuild the `.cpp` if you update the `.hpp`, for which there's no recipe.

I would therefore stick with your first version and, instead, consider using `vpath` for ease of maintenance

```
vpath %.cpp ./src/
vpath %.hpp ./include/
```

Comment: The GNU make maintainer wrote [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) for a reason.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you. I included the link in my answer.